# Install or use php composer in windows (fails)

Tags: php, installation, composer-php, packagist

so basically i was using composer on my windows installation without any problems. Suddenly i get this error on every project (installing composer.phar manually):

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Could not rename "Xampp\htdocs\symfony.dev\vendor/twig/twig/fabpot-Twig-  
  70fff8b" to "Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp/23cd0cd163431d8305983511f9  
  b1c2af".
```

I tried installing or updating on different php apps. Always the same result.

Also i tried to install composer via the windows setup which leads me to this error message:

```
Internal Error [ERR_LOGIC]: An internal script did not run correctly (exit code 1)
```

So far i couldn't get any official help. Anybody else experienced this error? Your help is appreciated... thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you check for permissions on both source and ouput directory shown in the error. Renaming failure are often cause by insufficient (write) permission. Maybe try to run as admin?

Comment: Also keep in mind that windows still has a 255 chars max path length

Comment: Also try clearing your temp folder. Maybe some file got corrupted. I can remember I've got a similar problem some time ago.

Answer (score 5):

When you run any command or start cmd. You have recived:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. 
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

If have, Try the following.

```
Open the Registry Editor, type regedit and hit Enter
Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun 
and clear the values.
```